# Application from /opt has no permissions

Tags: permissions, tor

I want to install the Tor Browser on Kubuntu.

I tend to slap everything into `~`, but it quickly gets messy. So, I'd like to install them "properly".

I downloaded the Tor Browser, ran

```
sudo cp -r tor-browser /opt && chmod -R 775 /opt/tor-browser
```

(I think it should go into `/opt`...?)

When the browser is launched it exits with

```
Tor browser does not have permission to access the profile.
Please adjust your file system permissions and try again.
```

However, if I simply launch it from `~/Downloads`, it all works.

What is the problem here?

Comment: The binary you are running probably writes to `.`.  You need to configure it or customize it to write to somewhere that it user-writable like `/var` or `~`.  Kubuntu/Debian has already done this configuration for you in the `torbrowser-launcher` package per Ipor's answer.

Comment: As I understand it, its permissions and ownership is `rwxrwx--x root root`, so if I'm neither `root` user or in the `root` group (and I launch it as myself, rather than `root`), it cannot write to `.`?

Comment: That's exactly correct.  To run it as your user, it needs to be run in a directory which is owned by you.  To run as any user, it needs to be run from a directory which is world-writable.  However there are nuances such as: keeping your user-data specific to your user, and making the working directory somewhere other than the directory the binary is in or arbitrary.  Also the location of config files and desktop/menu entries.  The package suggested handles all of this for you.  What's your aversion to installing the package?

Answer (score 2):

You have a package for it in your distro:

```
apt install torbrowser-launcher
```